# How to use ifelse on a vector with several calculations after if-statement (which uses entries from other vectors)

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I have several vectors in a function which are all of the same lengths (2000). I want to check with an if-statement whether some condition is met in one vector and then the code should do several calculations with the entries from the other vectors of the same row. So far, I could not solve it with the normal if-statement nor with the ifelse function. It could be solved with a loop but as I have 2000 observations, that would result in a long run-time of the code - which I would like to avoid.
My code looks like:

```
function1 = function(vec1,vec3,vec4,vec5){

ifelse(vec5 < 20,
# Calculations follow which should be executed when the statement is true
# The row used for vec1 and vec3 should be the same as the row which got 
# checked for vec5
a <- vec1 * 2 * vec3
b <-  vec1 * 4
c <- cbind(a,b)
d<- apply(c, 1, FUN=min),

# Now should be the calculations if the if-statement is false
# Again, the row used for vec1, vec3 and vec 4 should be the same as the row
# which got checked for vec5
a <- vec1 * 2 * vec3
b <-  vec1 * 4
c <- cbind(a,b)
d1<- apply(c, 1, FUN=min)
a2 <- vec1 * 1.5 * vec4
b2 <-  vec1 * 4
c2 <- cbind(a2,b2)
d2<- apply(c2, 1, FUN=min)
d = d1 + d2) # end of ifelse

return(d)
}

# For convenience lets just assume the vectors are of length 3
vec1 <- c(100,150,120)
vec3 <- c(12,20,28)
vec4 <- c(42,48,43)
vec5 <- c(18,17,25)

d <- function1(vec1,vec3,vec4,vec5)

# d should be a vector of length 3 as well with outcome 400,600,960 if I calculated correctly by hand
```

This code does not run as R seems to expect only one line of code after vec5<20 instead of all the different calculations. How can I solve this problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: just a word of meta advice. Solutions are going to be a lot simpler if the vectors are columns of a data.frame.

Comment: You need to store the return of the ifelse in d, by doing d <- ifelse(.......). Each code-part, that should be done within the if and else branch has to be within { }. So you basicaly have `d <- ifelse(vec5 < 20, { code in if case}, {code in else case})` and after that `return(d)`. But as @StephenHenderson said, i think it would be a good way to bind the vectors into one df first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, your function can be reduced to

```
function1 <- function(vec1,vec3,vec4,vec5){
    ifelse(vec5 < 20, pmin(vec1 * 2 * vec3, vec1 * 4), 
         pmin(vec1 * 2 * vec3, vec1 * 4) + pmin(vec1 * 1.5 * vec4,vec1 * 4))
}

function1(vec1, vec3, vec4, vec5)
#[1] 400 600 960
```

Or even better to avoid repetitive calculation and `ifelse`

```
function1 <- function(vec1,vec3,vec4,vec5){
  pmin(vec1 * 2 * vec3,   vec1 * 4) + 
      (pmin(vec1 * 1.5 * vec4,vec1 * 4)*(vec5 >= 20))
}

function1(vec1, vec3, vec4, vec5)
#[1] 400 600 960
```

Comment: `*(vec5 >= 20)` is a really nice idea :) definitely gonna steal this for some purpose :D

Comment: Both suggestions are great and very elegant solutions. Thanks a lot for the help!